# ghcup install fails when trying to install cabal

Tags: haskell, curl, installation, ghcup

When trying to install **ghcup** using curl from the official page, it throws the following error.

```
curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://get-ghcup.haskell.org | sh
```

Ubuntu:

```
Debug: Identified Platform as: Linux Ubuntu, 20.04
Debug: last access was 30.9227239s ago, cache interval is 300s
Debug: Decoding yaml at: /root/.ghcup/cache/ghcup-0.0.7.yaml
Warn: New ghc version available. To upgrade, run 'ghcup install ghc 9.2.1'
Debug: Requested to install cabal version 3.4.0.0
Info: downloading: https://downloads.haskell.org/~cabal/cabal-install-3.4.0.0/cabal-install-3.4.0.0-x86_64-ubuntu-16.04.tar.xz as file /tmp/ghcup-532680fdab846e84/cabal-install-3.4.0.0-x86_64-ubuntu-16.04.tar.xz
Error: Download failed: Process "curl" with arguments ["-fL", "-o",
                                                "/tmp/ghcup-532680fdab846e84/cabal-install-3.4.0.0-x86_64-ubuntu-16.04.tar.xz.tmp",
                                                "https://downloads.haskell.org/~cabal/cabal-install-3.4.0.0/cabal-install-3.4.0.0-x86_64-ubuntu-16.04.tar.xz"] failed with exit code 1.
```

Mac:

```
Debug: Identified Platform as: Darwin
Debug: last access was 124.44841s ago, cache interval is 300s
Debug: Decoding yaml at: /Users/orelvislagovasallo/.ghcup/cache/ghcup-0.0.7.yaml
Warn: New ghc version available. To upgrade, run 'ghcup install ghc 9.2.1'
Debug: Requested to install cabal version 3.4.0.0
Info: downloading: https://downloads.haskell.org/~cabal/cabal-install-3.4.0.0/cabal-install-3.4.0.0-x86_64-darwin-sierra.tar.xz as file /private/var/folders/d6/t4n84vb949z0w4lym5lp72yw0000gn/T/ghcup-df9e399af7820a34/cabal-install-3.4.0.0-x86_64-darwin-sierra.tar.xz
Error: Download failed: Process "curl" with arguments ["-fL", "-o",
                                                "/private/var/folders/d6/t4n84vb949z0w4lym5lp72yw0000gn/T/ghcup-df9e399af7820a34/cabal-install-3.4.0.0-x86_64-darwin-sierra.tar.xz.tmp",
                                                "https://downloads.haskell.org/~cabal/cabal-install-3.4.0.0/cabal-install-3.4.0.0-x86_64-darwin-sierra.tar.xz"] failed with exit code 1.
```